# Force diagram - Circular motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image: Bike in circular motion]

If the bike is maintaining a horizontal trajectory, what are the forces on it? The solution o this shows weight and a force labelled N at the angle a to the wall. I don't understand that because if N is the normal contact force, it should be perpendicular to the wall. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand that because if N is the normal contact force, it should be perpendicular to the wall

In this case they are just using the variable $N$ to represent the total contact force with the wall. The total contact force is, in general, not perpendicular to the wall.

It can be broken into a perpendicular component, usually called the normal force, and a parallel component, usually called the friction force. But those are just two components of the total contact force, and it is not mandatory to break the total contact force into those components. They are not separate forces, they are part of the same interaction.